# AuthenticationException LDAP using plain Java

Tags: java, authentication, exception, active-directory, ldap

i have a problem while connecting to an Active Directory via ldap using plain Java.

If the displayName begins with a , (Comma  e.g. ", name") I get a `javax.naming.AuthenticationException`. The displayName is never used in the application. `Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL` and  `Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS` wich I use dont contain any commas.

Can somebody explain this behaviour to me?

Some Stack:

```
javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C090334, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 525, vece]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(LdapCtx.java:3100)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:3046)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2848)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.connect(LdapCtx.java:2762)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.<init>(LdapCtx.java:329)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURL(LdapCtxFactory.java:206)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURLs(LdapCtxFactory.java:224)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getLdapCtxInstance(LdapCtxFactory.java:167)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getInitialContext(LdapCtxFactory.java:97)
```

Test-Client (just replace the placeholders):

```
import java.util.Hashtable;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.naming.directory.DirContext;
import javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext;

public class LdapClient {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {

        // URL to Active Directory
        String ldapContextUrl = ###URL###;
        //Login
        String ldapContextUserDn = ###USER###;
        //Password
        String ldapContextPassword = ###PASSWORD###;

        Hashtable<String, String> environment = new Hashtable<String, String>();

        environment.put( Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory" );
        environment.put( Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple" );
        environment.put( Context.STATE_FACTORIES, "PersonStateFactory" );
        environment.put( Context.OBJECT_FACTORIES, "PersonObjectFactory" );

        environment.put( Context.PROVIDER_URL, ldapContextUrl );
        environment.put( Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, ldapContextUserDn );
        environment.put( Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, ldapContextPassword );

        try {
            DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext( environment ); // Error occures here
        } catch( NamingException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Please dont say: *Dont use a displayName like this.* I am just interested, why the application behaves like described above. Is it a bug, a feature or something between?

You can also reproduce this problem by using *Apache Directory Studio* or *Websphere Application Server* (Security configured against LDAP). So the problem seems to be JVM-independent. Oracle and IBM behave similar.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In "out-of-the-box" AD would create the entry with the DN as: ", name,...,dc=example,dc=domain" I would imagine that the issue is that you have a dn with a comma. Comma's must be escaped within a DN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So .. i did some further investigations and got some new details.

It all has to do with the "Modes of Authenticating to LDAP". My client (maybe *Apache Directory Studio* or *Websphere Application Server* too) uses the *simple* Auth-Mode.

```
environment.put( Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple" );
```

If I change this to a more advanced mode the client is working fine.

```
environment.put( Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "DIGEST-MD5" );
```

See some Oracle-Doc:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/ldap/authentication.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/ldap/auth_mechs.html

I dont know why the Auth-Mode has something to do with the DisplayName, but my tests have shown, that Java is not the problem - as sad by *olexd* before.

For my test I used a console application called *AdFind*. This app enables me to repoduce the same behaviour as my client with a non-java-application

Answer (score 1):

Error code `525` in

```
LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C090334, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 525, vece
```

means `"user not found"` and is server-side error message. Thus, native Java JNDI or any other LDAP clients have no impacts on it. See [Data codes related to 'LDAP: error code 49' with Microsoft Active Directory](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21290631) for more details.

Comment: Hi! I read this some doc für LDAP error codes before, but "user not found" just didnt make any sence to me, because the user was definitely stored in AD.

I did some more investigations .. plz have a look at my next answer.